# heroku app crashes with socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, heroku, socket.io

The application, an API server meant to communicate with a Unity client was working just fine, until I added sockets. Manually testing socket.io using the chrome extension socket.io tester demonstrated that it is working just great on my local machine. Now that I've deployed it to heroku, it doesn't work. It crashes right off.

[image]

Typically, answers to this issue are all about the PORT not being set correctly, but in this case I have set the port to process.env.PORT, so there shouldn't be any problems with that. My app *was* working just fine until I added socket.io.

Here is my basic server file:

```
import express from "express"
import mongoose from "mongoose"
import http from "http"
import config from "./config/index.js"
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

// mongo
mongoose.connect(config.mongo.uri)
mongoose.connection.on("error", function(err) {
  console.error("MongoDB services error: " + err)
})

// server
let app = express()
let server = http.createServer(app)
let socketio = require("socket.io")(server)
require("./socketio").default(socketio)
require("./express").default(app)
require("./api").default(app)

// start
server.listen(config.port, function () {
  console.log("Listening on port: " + config.port)
})

export default app
```

Is there anything here to imply why the app may be crashing?

Answer (score 2):

So for anyone who might also be having trouble with Heroku in this way. It turns out that I had my config file with the proper port setting listed in my .gitignore file. (I don't know how it got there!) I wasn't paying attention to the logs when the app was starting up so I was missing the log that it the config file was missing. I was impressed by how Heroku's staff was able to point that out.

Comment: I am facing same issue. Yet not able to find the reason

Comment: Can you please explain how to add config file, and how to include the proper port setting? is there a sample config file somewhere?